# Emulator Extended Controls Location Android

Tags: android, android-emulator, location

[image]

I cant have latitude longitude co-ordinates because of the newly updated emulator can anyone help me out how could i change the location for google map testing app. I am really confused as it working fine before but after update this happened to me.

Comment: You can set location by putting marker on that map and then you will get to see the longitude and latitude of that below the map

Comment: Yes i will see that but i want to see the marker moving in my app as we change latitude longitude it effects the app simultaneously

Comment: You can do that programatically.